# Ionic 2 provider missing boilerplate load() function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am taking baby steps in ionic2. I am following [official blog tutorial](http://blog.ionicframework.com/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-calling-an-api/) to hit an api. I ran this command as instructed `ionic g provider PeopleService`. But the boilerplate code is something like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the PeopleServiceProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class PeopleServiceProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello PeopleServiceProvider Provider');
  }

}
```

**Insted of this**

```
load() {
  if (this.data) {
    // already loaded data
    return Promise.resolve(this.data);
  }

  // don't have the data yet
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // We're using Angular HTTP provider to request the data,
    // then on the response, it'll map the JSON data to a parsed JS object.
    // Next, we process the data and resolve the promise with the new data.
    this.http.get('path/to/data.json')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        // we've got back the raw data, now generate the core schedule data
        // and save the data for later reference
        this.data = data;
        resolve(this.data);
      });
  });
}
```

as mentioned in tutorial.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the `load` method is what you have to add to the generated page, I have never seen that kind of code (your second code block) being generated, only the first part is standard from a CLI-generated provider.

Comment: Yeah I think that bolg itself has various errors like it is importing `PeopleService` instead of `PeopleServiceProvider`. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: The naming strategies used in the CLI have changed a lot, not only class names but also file/folder names. Just use the latest version and study a generated project template, it seems they have stabilized in the last few months.